# Notepad++ - Regex Helper

Tags: notepad++

The past few updates have caused the regex helper plugin to raise an error when I try to open it:

[image]

This happens on ALL machines I have notepad++ running on. Does anyone have any idea how to get this plugin working?

Comment: If the API has changed, the plugin has to be updated. I suggest you contact the author of the plugin.

Comment: Go to plugins > Plugin manager > (updates tab) and check whether any plugin need an update.. Check the plugins and update it and then check the reported problem

Comment: No updates available

Answer (score 1):

If RegEx Helper is only a nice option for you, you can contact author of the plugin and wait for an update.

But if you badly need it, then you can downgrade your N++ to 6.6.9. RegEx Helper 0.0.2.2 works just fine with it. You can evaluate whether you really need all improvements that latest N++ has or whether you can afford to downgrade it.